# Texture not rendering on IOS

Tags: unity-game-engine

Essentially I am running the [catlike coding unity hexmap tutorial code](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/hex-map/) on IOS and I get this rendering error. [The full source code is here.](https://bitbucket.org/catlikecoding-projects/hex-map-project/src/665c9a8069420d3646369a9854177392f676a0f0/?at=release%2F2.2.0) Does anybody know what the issue could be? It works just fine on Android and PC but on all IOS devices (phone, ipad) I get this error.

Rivers and water render just fine but when it comes to the terrain textures they are really glitching out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Response courtesy of Jasper Flick at catlikecoding.com

> The glitched terrain that you're getting on iOS is likely due to the
> terrain texture array. In the series the texture array was made
> manually because Unity didn't support another way back when it was
> written. This means that the specific texture format and compression
> mode was fixed during asset creation and doesn't change with
> deployment target. The specific mode used ends up incompatible with
> iOS, resulting in garbage data being displayed.
>
> The solution is to create the texture array with the correct format.
> You can also now directly import a texture array and it will always
> use a compatible format, but you have to stitch the textures together
> into a flip book grid.